# Eclipse Stanford CoreNLP execution error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded"

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory, stanford-nlp

HI i am trying simple example from this official website of stanford CoreNLP example: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

***** TokensRegexNERAnnotator ner.fine.regexner: Read 585586 unique entries from 2 files
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.newNode(Unknown Source) *****

i had tried all solutions available on net, but i am unable to resolve issue
i had tried by increasing memory size in eclipse.ini file also tried by putting -Xms1024m in run configuration arguments.
I am working on my thesis tool please help me out i am stuck
i am using eclipse oxygen and stanford-corenlp-3.9.0

Thanks!

Comment: Try first using even more memory. 1GB is not THAT much for NLP, NLP is rather memory-hungry.

Comment: The memory size in the eclipse.ini is the size Eclipse uses for its own code. When you run a program the memory size is specified in the 'Run Configuration' for the program.

Comment: ok i am trying wait

Comment: oh no,
by changing to -Xms2048m in run configuration arguments
it just process from few more lines
but still after few processing got same error

Comment: TokensRegexNERAnnotator ner.fine.regexner: Read 585586 unique entries from 2 files
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.7 sec].
Adding annotator dcoref
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: final done by changing to -Xms3056m in run configuration arguments, but it hangs my laptop, but it completes task.. hurrryyy 
but do you know any other solution because my RAM is only 4 GB and if i give 3 GB to program my other work hangs

Answer (score 1):

final done by changing to -Xms3056m in run configuration arguments, mean i need more RAM because NLP takes much RAM to execute and compute

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is an IDE.  It has nothing to do with your problem.

This is a JVM runtime issue.

You need to answer a few questions:

1. Which version of JDK are you running?  JDK 8 eliminated perm gen and added meta space to the memory model.
2. Are you running a 64 bit JVM?
3. Have you profiled your app with Visual VM to see what the generations in memory are doing?

You can increase the max heap size beyond 1GB.

Comment: i think i have JDK 8 and 64 bit JVM
but can you please tell me how to check these things you are asking for?

Comment: Do a Google search and read up on JDK 8 memory configuration: http://blog.sokolenko.me/2014/11/javavm-options-production.html

Comment: final done by changing to -Xms3056m in run configuration arguments, but it hangs my laptop, but it completes task.. hurrryyy 
but do you know any other solution because my RAM is only 4 GB and if i give 3 GB to program my other work hangs

Comment: You need more RAM.  Stop everything else that is running on your laptop, including Eclipse.  It's a big memory hog.  Run outside of Eclipse.